# Why does my code only run when I use printf?

Tags: c

**EDIT**
Changing my Main method after the `end = clock();` call to:

```
    end = clock();
    unsigned long total_time = (end - start);
    u_llong total_iterations = (max - min);

    if ((u_llong)(total_time / CLOCKS_PER_SEC) > 0)
    {
        total_time = total_time / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        double ips = total_iterations / total_time;
        printf("Iterations per second: %f\n", ips);
        printf("Total time taken for %I64u iterations: %lu seconds.\n", total_iterations, total_time);
    }
    else
    {
        double ipms = total_iterations / total_time;
        printf("Iterations per millisecond: %f\n", ipms);
        printf("Total time taken for %I64u iterations: %lu ms.\n", total_iterations, total_time);
    }
    printf("---------------------\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    return 0;
    }
```

has done the trick for me..

**Here is the question again:**

I have a problem. When I compile this code using:`gcc main.c -Wall -std=c99 -lcrypto` I don't get any errors. However when I run the code in console it **should** output something like this:

> $ a.exe
> Starting 18446744073709551615 iterations now.
> Starting at 11144000000
> Done. Solution: caesar at 11144802215
> Total time taken for 802215 iterations: 16 seconds
> Iterations per second: 50138.000000
> $

However that is not the case. Instead all I get is:

> $ a.exe
> Starting 18446744073709551615 iterations now.
> Starting at 11144000000
> $

The program just stops executing and terminates before it finishes.
Now the bizarre thing:
when I put in a printf("some random string"); inside my for- loop it works perfectly.
I commented out the beforementioned printf(); so that you can see what I meant. I really don't understand why that is, where it comes from or how to fix it. why does my code only work when I use printf? I do not want to keep it because I would like to try and get this code to execute as fast as I can.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <openssl/sha.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef unsigned long long u_llong;

#ifndef PASSWORD
#define PASSWORD "52915A4731522B93613F74A52D26F6A62AC8C5BD" //caesar
#endif
const char *base62Table = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
const int base = 62;

void hexString(char *dest, unsigned char *bytes, int bytesLength)
{
    char lookup[16] = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'};
    for (int i = 0; i < bytesLength; i++)
    {
        dest[2 * i] = lookup[(bytes[i] >> 4) & 0xF];
        dest[2 * i + 1] = lookup[bytes[i] & 0xF];
    }
    dest[2 * bytesLength] = 0;
}

void genHash(char *str, unsigned char *dest)
{
    SHA1((unsigned char *)str, strlen(str), dest);
}

int check(char *str)
{
    unsigned char hash[SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH] = {0};
    char hex[41] = {0};
    genHash(str, hash);
    hexString((char *)hex, (unsigned char *)hash, sizeof(hash));
    hex[40] = '\0';
    return strcmp(PASSWORD, hex) == 0;
}

void to_base(u_llong num, char *out)
{
    const int base = 62;
    if (num == 0)
    {
        out[0] = '0';
        out[1] = '\0';
        return;
    }
    int i = 0;
    while (num != 0)
    {
        out[i++] = base62Table[(num % base)];
        num /= base;
    }
    out[i] = '\0';
    out = strrev(out);
}

void run(u_llong *min, u_llong *max, char *str)
{
    //Right solution should come at i = 11144802215
    for (u_llong i = *min; i < *max; i++)
    {
        to_base(i, str);
        //printf("I only work when using this\n");
        if (check(str))
        {
            printf("Done. Solution: %s at %I64u\n", str, i);
            *max = i;
            break;
        }
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    u_llong max = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF, min = 11144000000; //start shortly before the right solution comes up
    clock_t start, end;
    printf("Starting %I64u iterations now.\nStarting at %I64u\n", max, min);
    fflush(stdout);
    const int length = 20;
    char str[length + 1];
    //Start executing the actual task
    start = clock();
    run(&min, &max, str);
    end = clock();
    //finished executing the task
    unsigned long total = (end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    u_llong total_iterations = (max - min);
    double ips = (max - min) / total;
    printf("Total time taken for %I64u iterations: %lu seconds \n", total_iterations, total);
    printf("Iterations per second: %f\n", ips);
    fflush(stdout);
    return 0;
}
```

**---EDIT---**

I am compiling and running on a Windows 10 OS using Mingw64.
The format string %llu does not work in my GCC (it is "unknown"), so i use %I64u which works.

When I try to Run it using gdb (after adding `-g` flag to compiler) I get:

> $ gdb a.exe
> GNU gdb (GDB) 7.8
> Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
> License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
> This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
> There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
> and "show warranty" for details.
> This GDB was configured as "i686-w64-mingw32".
> Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
> For help, type "help".
> Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
> Reading symbols from a.exe...done.
> $

when I then use the `bt` command to "bt -- Print backtrace of all stack frames" it simply says:

> No stack.

**--- edit ---**

So I added a `Sleep(1)`; included from `windows.h` and now it does not crash on startup for some reason. Can it really be running "too" fast? I am so confused

Someone pointed out that `end == start`. This is not the case as the same crash happens even when I wrap it in

```
//...
end = clock();
if (end == start)
    {
        printf("End equals start");
    }
    else
    {
        unsigned long total = (end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        double ips = (max - min) / total;
        printf("Iterations per second: %f\n", ips);
        u_llong total_iterations = (max - min);
        printf("Total time taken for %I64u iterations: %lu seconds \n", total_iterations, total);
    }
    //...
```

Comment: Single step through the code with your debugger...

Comment: `"%I64u"` is not a valid format specifier. If you want to use and print a 64 bit unsigned integer, use `int64_t` from `<stdint.h>` and use `"%"PRIu64` as a format specifier. The correct format specifier for `unsigned long long` is `"%llu"` which is at least 64 bit but can be more.

Comment: Really? @12431234123412341234123 because my compiler does not throw any fits against it. for me its working. but I will change it then

Comment: [Heisenbugs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug) often are due to memory corruption. You pass around a lot of output buffers without passing along their corresponding sizes, which is an error-prone practice and which makes the code harder to reason about.  You also have a lot of hard-coded sizes instead of expressing them in terms of other quantities. (For example, `41` should be `SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH * 2 + 1`.)

Comment: I see, I will change that and see if the bug still occurres

Comment: @Kuro-dev Yes, my compiler also warns about it, same for `strrev()` which is not available. Are you on a specific platform that has some extensions? If so, please mention it or add a tag.

Comment: Edited. I am running on Win 10 with Mingw64. Sadly I cannot provide a lot of info about what libs I use and stuff, I have only just started learning and simply downloaded everything that win-builds 1.50 offered me, in terms of C related things.

Comment: I compiled the code --after adding a `strrev` implementation-- on a Linux system (Ubuntu 20.04 64bit). When I run it I get the output "Done. Solution: caesar at...", but a floating point exception at the line `double ips = (max - min) / total;` because `total` is 0. Valgrind does not find a memory access problem. Changing the type to `uint64_t` and fixing the format specifier doesn't change this. The only problem on my system is the floating point exception because the function `run` seems to run too fast (less than 1 sec) here. Adding the `printf` will make it much slower fixing the div by 0.

Comment: @Bodo I don't get why it works for you. For me it just terminates instantly when I don't use the Printf. Can a program be too fast for execution on windows, so it gets terminated?

Comment: Maybe it works for me because I use a different OS. Compile the program with debug information, i.e. add option `-g` to the compile command. Run the program in a debugger, e.g. execute `gdb a.exe` or `gdb ./a.exe` and type `run`. If it crashes the debugger should show you at which location in the code the problem was found. (This might be different from the location that caused the problem.) You can use the GDB command `where` to get a stack trace. If the program seems to terminate normally, run it step-by-step to find out what is going wrong. An IDE may make it easier to use the debugger.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123: [`I64` is a Microsoft prefix; `%I64u` is a valid conversion specification in MSVC for `unsigned __int64`.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa261215(v=vs.60).aspx)

Comment: And Mingw uses MSVC libs that don't confirm to standard C. You can partially unmicrosoft it by adding `#define __USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO 1` before you `#include <stdio.h>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
unsigned long total = (end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
double ips = (max - min) / total;
```

When you add an additional `printf`, the code happens to run for long enough so that `total` is not zero.

Without the `printf`, your code is fast enough that it executes faster then a second, so `(end - start) < CLOCKS_PER_SEC`. Because of that `(end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC` is zero, `total` is equal to zero and when dividing by zero your program gets terminated when receiving an `SIGFPE` signal (arithmetic exception).

This is a perfect case to brush up your debugger skills, such case is easily detectable with a debugger.

Comment: While this has solved the run issue, the question still remains. My code takes (considerably) longer than 1 second to execute. how can total be 0?

Comment: `My code takes (considerably) longer than 1 second to execute` most probably the difference in `clock()` output is just below 1 second, which happens to reuslt in `total` being equal to 0. Note that `clock()` is not real-time execution, but some "cpu clocks" used by your process. The whole program with termination takes 0.7 second on my pc.

Comment: read the edit I provided in my question at the bottom. even when I wrap it in an if-statement it crashes on startup. instantly at that. its so weird

Comment: I run the code in Linux, except the `%I64u` have some printf problem, all works correct.  The calculate start at 11144000000, end at 11144802215.  So I think take less then 1 second to process 802215 integer is reasonable.

Comment: @Kuro-dev check for `total == 0`, not for `end == start`. You could check for `end - start < CLOCKS_PER_SEC`. The output is buffered and may not be flushed on process termination -  add `fflush(0)` to flush the output.

Comment: @randomeval yes, that seems to have been it. my god. I made a horrible mistake here. haha I was sitting here for over 5 hours to figure this out